# Material Appears Black When Image is Rendered (F12) But looks Fine in rendered View

Tags: rendering, materials

So i have a Sphere With a Material The Sphere Appears Fine In rendered View But. Appears Completley Black when The image Is rendered (using F12 key)
Here is An image of what i am experiencing
[image]

and what i should be seeing

[image]

Also here is a link of the Blend file

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uTVrtKPJItXldAYbpHPTEeToorfzBM-u/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Most likely the object that's hidden (Sphere.001) in viewport is not hidden in render and is obstructing light

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sphere.001 is not visible in render view because you have disabled that but it is visible in the final render:

[image: sphere.001 visibility]

Disable Sphere.001 in the render by clicking on the camera icon:

[image: sphere.001 disabled in render]

and it will render fine.